# Why my automatic pager stop runing after i swipe it manually?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have following the step to make automatic viewpager in github conversation issue, and im getting bug in my viepager , im using jetpack compose.
I have following the step to make automatic viewpager in github conversation issue, and im getting bug in my viepager , im using jetpack compose.

**My Pager Configruatin**

```
Box {
    HorizontalPager(count = items.size, state = pagerState) { page ->
        AutomaticSliderCard(item = items[page],Modifier.onSizeChanged { pageSize = it })
    }
```

**MyScreen
**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Composable
fun DashboardScreen(navController: NavController) {
    val items = DashboardSlider1.getData()
    val itemsBanner = dummyBannerDashboardItem
    val itemsKenalan = dummyKenalanDashboardItem

    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
    var pageSize by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero) }
    val lastIndex by remember(pagerState.currentPage) {
        derivedStateOf { pagerState.currentPage == items.size - 1 }
    }

    val pagerStateBanner = rememberPagerState()


    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        while (true) {
            yield()
            delay(2000)
            pagerState.animateScrollBy(
                value = if (lastIndex) -(pageSize.width.toFloat() * items.size) else pageSize.width.toFloat(),
                animationSpec = tween(if (lastIndex) 2000 else 1400)
            )
        }
    }
```

```
@Composable
fun AutomaticSliderCard(item: DashboardSlider1, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(200.dp)
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.background_dashboard_slider1),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            alignment = Alignment.Center,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        )
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.CenterStart)
                .offset(y = -20.dp)
        ) {
            Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start) {
                Text(
                    text = item.title.toString(),
                    fontFamily = Poppins,
                    fontSize = 20.sp,
                    color = Color.White,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 24.dp)
                )
                Text(
                    text = "${item.numberCount}",
                    fontFamily = Poppins,
                    fontSize = 25.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    color = Color.White,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(horizontal = 24.dp)
                        .offset(y = -10.dp)
                )
            }
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = item.image),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier.size(120.dp),
                alignment = Alignment.CenterEnd
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    snapshotFlow { pagerState.currentPage }
        .debounce(2000L)
        .onEach {
            pagerState.animateScrollBy(
                value = if (lastIndex) - (pageSize.width.toFloat() * items.size) else pageSize.width.toFloat(),
                animationSpec = tween(if (lastIndex) 2000 else 1400)
            )
        }
        .launchIn(this)
}
```

Here `snapshotFlow` will listen your current page and start animation if last changes was be make more than 2 seconds ago.

Comment: thanks brow, it's working to my code

Answer (score -1):

Try updating your **LaunchedEffect** key

```
LaunchedEffect(key1= Unit, key2= pagerState.currentPage) {
    while (true) {
        yield()
        delay(2000)
        pagerState.animateScrollBy(
            value = if (lastIndex) -(pageSize.width.toFloat() * items.size) else pageSize.width.toFloat(),
            animationSpec = tween(if (lastIndex) 2000 else 1400)
        )
    }
}
```

Also, i advice you to use **animateScrollToPage** instead of **animateScrollBy**:

```
LaunchedEffect(key1= Unit, key2= pagerState.currentPage) {
    while (true) {
        yield()
        delay(2000)
        var newPage = pagerState.currentPage + 1
        if (newPage > items.lastIndex) newPage = 0
        pagerState.animateScrollToPage(newPage)
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, i just follow this and getting weird with my pager transform. could you have any way ?

Comment: Which version of pager you are using? There is an issue with latest releases of pager version. I hope you will not see issue in pager_version=0.23.1

Comment: Also, check edited answer for better results

Comment: With versions after 0.23.1, there is issue like page is not scrolled fully, instead it shows half scolled view!

Comment: https://github.com/google/accompanist/issues/1261, this is link that i follow. thanks megh you give me more insight